# Getting ipv4 instead of ipv6 in jsf

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

I want to get the IP address of a client in a remote machine.I am using this code :

```
public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
}
```

But it always returns the `IPv6`, is there a way to have an `IPv4`?

Comment: This problem is not related with JSF at all.

Comment: I know, but i hoped that JSF would have an approach to work around this thing

Comment: I hope you have some security layer in front of this code that prevents the client from forging these headers.

Comment: @PerJohansson what do you mean ?

Comment: @Ced This code parses headers sent by the client. The client can put whatever they want in there, e.g. sql injections, or someone else's ip. There needs to be a proxy in front of this code that disable such forging, or there isn't much value of getting the (possibly forged) IP at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an IPv6 address then IPv6 is being used. IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols, and the client chooses which one to use when both are available.

If you want the client's IPv4 address then you can force them to use it by not advertising the IPv6 address in DNS. That would be a bad idea though with the increasing deployment of IPv6. Supporting both is good, so it is better to deal with clients using IPv6.

Comment: thanks for answering the question, but how could i force the DNS to not advertise IPv6, i am new to DNS configurations

Comment: That completely depends on your local setup so I can't answer that question. You should talk to your DNS provider.